# Force first page to be marked as right page in PDF

Tags: pdfpages, double-sided

I am using the `pdfpages` package to combine two pdf documents into a single one:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-22]{doc1}
\includepdf[pages=-]{doc2}
\includepdf[pages=30-]{doc1}
\end{document}
```

This works, however my PDF viewers (okular, evince) assume that the first page is a left page. How can I force the first page to be marked as right page in the PDF?

Comment: Try `\includepdf[pages=1-22,openright=true]{doc1}`.

Comment: You are missing a closing brace in the forelast line.

Comment: @Sigur: Thanks, but then the document still starts with a left page, as `\includepdf` just inserts an empty page before.

Comment: The PDF format does not know about "left" and "right" pages. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I was under the impression that it did, given that (with a double-page view), I've seen documents start sometimes on a right and sometimes on a left page. After your comment I rechecked and indeed it seems just to depend on the viewer (settings), not on the document. This makes the my question pointless, of course .

Comment: This is not a problem with the PDF file, but rather with the settings of the viewers. In Evince you can go to `View` and untick `Odd pages left` and use the `Dual` view. I assume something similar is available in the view settins in Okular as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a problem of viewer settings.